# Размещающий new и явный вызов деструктора

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Создал класс:

```
template <typename T> class Vector {
   static const size_t def_capacity = 10;
public:
   Vector():capacity{ 0 }, size{ 0 }, mas{ nullptr } {}     
   Vector(size_t siz) :capacity{ siz }, size{ siz } {
        T* tmp = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * siz);
        mas = new(tmp) T[siz];
   }
    ~Vector() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            mas[i].~T();

         free(mas);
    }


    T operator[](int i) const {
        return mas[i];
    }
    T& operator[](int i) {
        return mas[i];
    }
}
private:
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    T* mas;
};
class V {
public:
    V():p{new char[10]}{}
    ~V() {
    delete[] p;
}
private:
    char * p;
};
```

Хотел проверить таким  кодом:

```
#include "new.h"

void foo() {
    Vector<V> vec(10);
}
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Но получаю это:

> Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через отладчик просмотрел, что все деструкторы вызываются правильно, но ошибка появляется перед free(mas) в деструкторе Vector, если закоментить, ошибки не будет.
Возможно что-то напартачил с явным вызовом деструктора, ибо на int ошибок не было. Использую Visual Studio.

UPD: 
Ещё раз пересмотрел все через отладчик и выяснил что на строчке

```
 T* tmp = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * siz);
```

Возвращается указатель, который на 4 байта (предположительно размер V) меньше, чем позже возвращает new

```
  mas = new(tmp) T[siz];
```

который я и записываю в поле mas. Позже, пытаясь очистить память free(mas) выскакивает ошибка, ибо я адрес то уже не тот, который вернул malloc.

Пробовал еще записывать адрес, возвращаемый malloc-ом и удалять его, но уже появились другие ошибки.

Comment: Напиши ошибку текстом.

Comment: Ошибку нужно в вопросе процитировать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placement-new, примененный в синтаксисе массива, в общем случае *возвращает не то же самое значение указателя, которое было передано в него*, ибо он может использовать часть памяти для хранения служебной информации (например, размер массива). Это означает, что, во-первых, блок памяти, выделенный как `malloc(sizeof(T) * siz)` в общем случае не достаточен для хранения массива `T[siz]` при условии инициализации через placement-new[]. И, во-вторых, передавать полученный из placement-new[] указатель обратно во `free` нельзя - он в общем случае не совпадает по значению с тем указателем, который был получен из `malloc`.

Именно по этим причинам ваш код будет падать в случаях, когда тип `T` имеет нетривиальный деструктор (как у вас в примере).

Если я не упускаю каких-то нововведений, не существует корректного/портабельного способа использования "массивной" версии placement-new, ибо нет портабельного способа узнать заранее, сколько памяти ему понадобится. И даже если вы каким-то образом выкрутитесь с объемом памяти, все равно вам придется либо запоминать, либо восстанавливать правильное значение указателя, полученное из `malloc` - для передачи во `free`.

Наилучший выход в данном случае - прекратите пользоваться "массивным" placement-new вообще, а лучше сделайте обычный placement-new отдельно для каждого элемента массива. Вы уже фактически сделали аналогичный шаг на этапе деструкции, т.е. вызываете деструктор для каждого элемента индивидуально. Вот так же сделайте и конструкцию - через placement-new для каждого элемента индивидуально.

А в C++17 лучше воспользуйтесь готовыми стандартными функциями. Для корректной конструкции/деструкции массивов при ручном выделении сырой памяти уже есть готовые функции типа `std::uninitialized_default_construct`, `std::destroy_n` и т.п. (см. `<memory>`). Не надо приплетать сюда явный массивный placement-new.

Comment: Вы правы, всё нормализовалось когда начал добавлять 4 байта к выделяемой памяти и удалять начальный указатель. Как-то это очень гадко выглядит, но другого выхода пока что не найти.

Comment: @Виталий Волк:  "добавлять 4 байта"? Ну так теперь попробуйте тип без деструктора (напр. `T == int`) и все снова начнет падать. Как я уже сказал выше, нормального решения с массивным placement-new нет. И всякие "добавлять 4 байта" - это лишь мертвому припарки.